# installing an image of a VM on an external hard drive for dual boot

Tags: linux, virtualbox, external-hard-drive, multi-boot

I'm working on a virtual machine (Linux Mint on VirtualBox, with Win7 as host), but for better performances I'm thinking about installing Linux directly on an external eSATA and dual-boot.

Is it possible to directly install the content of the image on the external drive, to avoid the pain of reinstalling the tools and reconfiguring the system from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the image using clonezilla, ghost or something similar, but most likely you would have to use a rescue procedure to create a boot kernel with the correct modules for your hardware.